# IIS with Maximum worker process = 3 is not working if i set it to 1 then it is working fine

Tags: iis-7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0tfJ.png)

I m using mode as SqlServer. If i set Maximum Worker Process to 3 then getting  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. If it is 1 then working fine.

sessionState allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false" mode="SQLServer" sqlCommandTimeout="1800" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=MyLocal;initial catalog=MyDB;user id=sa;password=ABC" timeout="30" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"

Please refere image to see iis application pool setting

Comment: Your question is about iis not c#. change it to iis. and give more information about iis server

Comment: Running your web app on three worker processes mean a lot of changes of the execution. I don't expect a not-well-written app can perfectly adapt to such changes. Identify the code that fails to work and fix it.